# D3 - pass variable to x value

Tags: d3.js

I have a codepen here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvgJKB

I have a simple stacked bar chart

I'm passing content on the x axis using

```
.attr('x', (d, i) => {
    return x(d.data.date)
})
```

`date` is a value in the data array

```
let dataToStack = [{
    "usedInf": 20,
    "newInf": 32,
    'totalInf': 73,
    "date": "2015-05-31T00:00:00"
}, {
    "usedInf": 100,
    "newInf": 120,
    'totalInf': 103,
    "date": "2015-06-30T00:00:00"
}, {
    "usedInf": 60,
    "newInf": 45,
    'totalInf': 93,
    "date": "2015-07-31T00:00:00"
},
];
```

Is it possbile to pass in the `date` part of the return statment

I was thinking something like

```
.attr('x', (d, i) => {
    var value = date
    var link = 'd.data'+value
    return x(link)
})
```

I want to do this so I can make the D3 compoenent I'm building more reuseable so I want to be able to pass this in based on the data I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access properties of a javascript object like so:

```
someObject[somePropertyString]
```

From your example:

```
    .attr('x', (d, i) => {
        //return x(d.data.date)
        var link = d.data[xAxisValue];                         
        return x(link)
    })
```